# Whether a combination reaction goes to completion

Tags: reaction-mechanism

There is a sentence in my textbook:

> When a combination reaction results in a gas that is allowed to be
>   released, a precipitate that drops to the bottom of the container, or
>   a nonionizing product, the reaction will go to completion.

What is meant by "the reaction will go to completion"? Does it mean all of the reactions will be converted to products and no reverse reaction occurs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It generally means that the reaction is irreversible (no reverse reaction occurs), or that the extent of the reverse reaction is so small as to be of no consequence.  This is the case for many precipitation reactions.  They are technically reversible in that some of the precipitate is in equilibrium with solvated ions, but the relative amounts are small.